# Why do I have an error when I try to override a generic binding with Guice? (TypeLiteral)

Tags: java, android, generics, guice

I'd like to override a generic type binding, but I allways got the same "`No implementation was bound`" error.

I'm using roboguice 3.

Here is a exemple of code that I use:

```
public interface IParser<I, O> {}

public class Parser1 implements IParser<String, String> {
    IParser<String, String> mParser;

    @Inject
    public Parser1(IParser<String, String> parser) {
        mParser = parser;
    }
}

public class Parser2 extends Parser1 {
    @Inject
    public Parser2(IParser<String, String> parser) {
        super(parser);
    }
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<IParser<String, String>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<Parser1>() {});
    }
}
```

And here is my injector creation :

```
RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(this,
                RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE,
                RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this),
                Modules.override(new MyModule()).with(new AbstractModule() {
                    @Override
                    protected void configure() {
                        bind(new TypeLiteral<IParser<String, String>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<Parser2>() {});
                    }
                })
);
```

If I don't try to override it (only user Parser1), all is fine, when I override standard object with providers, it works well too, but not with TypeLiteral.

My error is :

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
1) No implementation for IParser<String, String> was bound.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody have a clue ? Does Aurélien need to provide more informations ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior under Guice 4. I would note that there is a circular dependency, which Guice is using a proxy class shim to  satisfy. Could Roboguice be disabling proxies somewhere?

Comment: Side note: you never need to `new TypeLiteral<ASimpleType>() {}`, you can just use `ASimpleType.class`

Answer (score 6):

You should change definition of classes which are implemented your interface.

Try this:

```
public class Parser1<I, O> implements IParser<I, O> {
}
public class Parser2<I, O> extends Parser1<I, O> {
}
```

And then you can bind your interface to class by this way:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<IParser<String, String>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<Parser1<String, String>() {});
```

Comment: It shouldn't require type parameters on the implementing classes, adding them will have no effect on how Guice treats the binding.

Comment: In this case you would get "I" cannot be resolved to a type in line one of your answer. This doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not shure, but it looks remarkable to me that a binding to a conrete instance is used instead to a `Class`:

bind(new TypeLiteral>() {}).to(**new TypeLiteral() {}**);

did you try

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<IParser<String, String>>() {}).to(Parser2.class});
```

?

Comment: Binding to the type literal instance is equivalent to binding to the class.